# Ideas on adfs loading screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc, adfs, adfs2.0, federation

In our application we use adfs but there is a problem, after posting a username and password to adfs it takes arround 4 seconds before a page is loaded. In those 4 seconds only a white page is shown before the correct page is loaded. Is there any way to show some sort of loading screen in those 4 seconds? We use asp.net MVC. Thanks in advance

Comment: what have you tried so far? Show us some of the relevant code so we can see exactly what you did and why its doing what its doing.

Comment: @depperm I understand that you need some code, the only problem is this project is quite confidential, so I can't share any code.

Comment: Do check the advice of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31393577/adfs-loading-page-while-busy. It is almost always the Application that goes through JIT, initializes user context, shopping cart etc. Fiddler will show you the guilty page.